# The answer counter will not produce a value, what do I do?

Tags: python

```
answer = 0 #Makes a new counter and sets it to zero
max = 1000 #Sets the maximum value of the range
for i in range(1, max): #Takes the a value in the range
    if i%3 == 0 or i%5==0: #Finds the values that are divisble by 5 or 3 with no remainders
        answer = answer + i #Takes the counter and adds the number that is divisible
print "The sum of all mulitples of 3 or 5, below 1000 is" 
print answer #Prints the sum of all numbers divisble by 3 or 5 below 1000
```

Comment: Please update your question with both the actual output of this program and the output you were expecting.

Comment: `max` is a builtin, so using that as a variable name is discouraged. Your code produces the correct output too:

    The sum of all mulitples of 3 or 5, below 1000 is
    233168

Comment: I just tried your progran, in Python 3.x (only adding '()'), and works.